# Common anode 7 segment display

Tags: arduino

I've hooked up my arduino to a 7 segment display with a common anode..

[image: Awesome schematic]

At first I thought it wouldn't work at all because I was setting the pins on the cathode side of the LEDs to high.. then I discovered when I set the pins to the cathodes high the LEDs turn off..

Which is good, because I just needed to do a binary NOT (pretty much) on the output.

However, I don't really understand what's going on.. when the cathodes aren't set high, how is this the same as them being ground? Can someone please tell me what's going on here? I don't quite see how the circuit is complete..

Comment: Please share a schematic, it's easier to understand at a glance than a verbal description.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jj9jkgl71htv5sc/2013-03-20%2014.41.35.jpg - Please note there are resistors between the 595 and the display too for each pin out of the 595.

Comment: Also apologies for how bad that 'schematic' is :p I'm meant to be working..

Comment: Congratulations on the most awesome schematic I've ever seen on this site :-) ... Also, we don't do the "*Thanks, me*" stuff on posts around here. To thank someone, upvote their answers.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/724yvvbfrk1b29g/2013-03-20%2015.10.11.jpg < Updated diagram with pin numbers, more care (but not loads)..

Comment: Again I forgot to draw on the resistors between 595 and the display.. oops

Comment: *Please* don't update the schematic again. If I see another 2 MB JPG of a hand drawn sketch, I'll faint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how the output of most logic chips works.  When they are high, they are connected to the 5 volt supply, and when they are low, they are connected to ground.  You saw this yourself; you just didn't believe it.

Equally important is why the LED is off when the output is high.  When the cathode and anode are both at 5 volts, there is no voltage difference between them, and the LED does not light.  Many beginners have trouble understanding the nature of voltage.

Comment: Excellent, that makes sense. I suspected this was what was happening, but I am just starting out so it helps to have someone confirm my assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

Not setting the cathodes high doesn't mean they are grounded. It depends on the circuit connected to the cathodes.

If the circuit is open-collector transistors, when active they will connect the cathodes to ground but when they are inactive they will go open circuit (like a relay contact) and the cathodes will float at a voltage near the anode and the segments of the display will not be "on".

Maybe you are using a different drive circuit?